# Cant bake from cakephp app folder on windows 8

Tags: php, cakephp, windows-8, xampp, cakephp-bake

I have a default cakephp project i used on a lot of projects on win 7, now im trying to use it to bake on win 8. 
 Im using Xampp for apache/php and cakephp 2.0.

I have defined the system variables on path:
C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\htdocs\crudteste\lib\Cake\Console\;

If i run cake from any folder on command line, it works, but when i run it from the project\app folder it shows an empty string on console;

[image: Using cake command on another folder and on project/app folder]

The same happens if i try to cake bake all on app folder.
 
I have tryied to access cake console from app folder using ../lib/cake/console/cake but it shows the same empty string.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try running `echo %PATH%` and see if its in the path correctly. Have you restarted the console session since you added the environment variable?

Secondly, from the current location you are at, you should be able to access it using `Console\cake` This would be a better idea as you would always be using the correct version of the console to correspond with the version of cake you are using

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem was a corrupty file on cakephp installation, i have downloaded another and everything works.